# How can I copy text from input

Tags: javascript

I write with translate.

I want the input text to appear in the paragraph, then click the button .

html code:

```
<input id="demo">
<button onclick="myFunction()">Click me</button>
<p id="test"></p>
```

JS code:

```
var txt = JSON.parse(demo);
function myFunction() {
```

```js
var txt = JSON.parse(demo);
function myFunction() {
  document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = txt;
}
```

```html
<input id="demo">
<button onclick="myFunction()">Click me</button>

<p id="test"></p>
```

Comment: `JSON.parse(demo);` <= where is the demo variable coming from?  I don't see any logic connecting it to your input field.

Comment: @Taplar Element IDs become global variables automatically.

Comment: @Barmar egh, that's a terrible thing to rely upon...

Comment: @Taplar I agree, I didn't do it in my answer. But it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to get the value of the input in the function. There's no need to use `JSON.parse`.

```js
function myFunction() {
  document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = document.getElementById("demo").value;
}
```

```html
<input id="demo">
<button onclick="myFunction()">Click me</button>

<p id="test"></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function copyToParagraph() {
  var inputValue = document.getElementById('txtInput').value;
  var paragraphEle = document.getElementById('par');
  paragraphEle.innerHTML = inputValue;
  console.log(inputValue);
  console.log(paragraphEle);
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="txtInput" />
<br/>
<button onclick="copyToParagraph()">Click Me to Copy</button>
<br/><br/><br/>

<p id="par"></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to make a `var input = document.getElementById('input').value;` So that you have the value. Then do this:

```js
function myFunction() {
var input = document.getElementById('input').value;
document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML = input;
}
```